# How much flexibility does the `eso-pic` package have?

Tags: positioning, eso-pic

I want to put a background image in the upper right corner of the text block. The `eso-pic` package looks about right, but the commands listed in the manual only refer to the left side of the page, as in `\AtTextUpperLeft` and so forth. Are there commands for the right side of the page? In other words, is there an `\AtTextUpperRight`? And if not, is there a way to place the image where I need it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `Right` counterpart to the exists `Left`s. But you can move stuff into position:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
  \AtTextUpperLeft{%
    \makebox[\textwidth][r]{% Move over to right so right aligns with right of text block
      \raisebox{-\height}{% Drop down so top aligns with top of text block
        \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

My guess is that the focus on `Left` placement stems from the fact that the items are set left-aligned, meaning they extend towards the right. For a `Right` placement, one would need to make sure that items extend towards the left (maybe).

These might be a start:

```
\newcommand{\AtTextUpperRight}[1]{%
  \AtTextUpperLeft{%
    \hspace*{\textwidth}%
    #1%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\AtTextLowerRight}[1]{%
  \AtTextLowerLeft{%
    \hspace*{\textwidth}%
    #1%
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `eso-pic`, you can use [`background`](http://ctan.org/pkg/background) with [`tikzpagenodes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) help.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}% Just for this example

\backgroundsetup{%
scale=1,
angle=0,
contents={\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}},
position=current page text area.north east,
anchor=below left,
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice, +1, although the rationale behind `anchor=below left` escapes me...

Comment: @Rmano, if you prefer can use `nodeanchor=north east` instead of `anchor=below left`. In `TiKZ` expressions like `below` or `above right` can be used to place nodes. As example `below` means that the node will be placed with its `north` as a reference point, `above right` with anchor `south west` and so one.